Looker Studio GA4 Date Field creating a Custom Display Format
I'm trying to creat custom date format for my times series chart. Which currently is using the long 'Custom date format' which i have screenshot below.
Graph of the issue

Current date format being used

I want to get this format show as Nov 4 - Nov 10, 2024 but am having no luck in figuring out the code for 'Nov 10'
Custom date Format Wanted

